# PHP не отображает ошибки

Tags: php, linux

Здравствуйте.
Мой PHP не отображает ошибки в скрипте. В `php.ini`, параметр

```
error_recording = E_ALL
```

С чем ещё может быть связана проблема и как её исправить?

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, только в ОС Виндовс. Если ошибка в скрипте браузер выдает 500-ую ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас написано re**c**ording, вместо re**p**orting.

И тем не менее - по умолчанию, в php.ini имеем:

```
; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Что-бы включить отображение ошибок изменяем на:

```
; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
    Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Т.е. просто раскомментируем нужную нам директиву. После, естественно, перезагружаем apache.